# Preserve window layout in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I have setup my windows in a certain way.  How do I save this setting to be invoked later?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Check out emacs [desktop](http://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/emacs/Saving-Emacs-Sessions.html). I have no emacs available but I believe it's part of the standard lisp packages you get when you install emacs.

> Use the desktop library to save the
>   state of Emacs from one session to
>   another. Once you save the Emacs
>   desktop—the buffers, their file names,
>   major modes, buffer positions, and so
>   on—then subsequent Emacs sessions
>   reload the saved desktop.

Comment: I use desktop-save-mode to store the buffers and use workgroups to store the arrangement of my frames and windows. https://github.com/tlh/workgroups.el.

Comment: This answer may be misleading for some, I believe the author is confusing "frames" with "windows". The linked *desktop* package only supports restoring of frames (which outside of the emacs universe are called windows), but actual emacs windows are not persisted. Also downvoted because author doesn't appear to have actually tried it out.

Comment: Downvoted, the author should have used it before recommending a library as a solution.

Comment: I can confirm that it doesn't work as quite described in the quote above!  It restores all of the buffers, but not the window layout.  The problem seems to be, at least in part, that the windows are themselves populated with "computed" contents" (like Org Agenda with various settings)! — So, in order to actually restore what I had before, it would have to either recompute everything, or write the buffer contents to disk.  Since it doesn't seem to do either of those things, it's of limited use as a true "checkpointing" mechanism.

Answer (score 76):

I sometimes still use `C-x r w <register>` to store a window configuration in a register, and `C-x r j <register>` (where `<register>` is a single character) to jump back to it.

While this is a nice way for storing a few window configurations which you want to go back to after some time, I find [winner-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WinnerMode) to be more convenient in a few regards. (For example, you won't have to bother naming the configurations).

Just put `(winner-mode 1)` in your .emacs, bind `winner-undo` and `winner-redo` to convenient shortcuts (or use the IMHO awkward `C-c <left>` and `C-c <right>` predefined ones), and you'll be able to switch back to previous window configurations.

See also: `M-: (info "(emacs) Window Convenience")` and `M-: (info "(emacs) RegConfig")`

Comment: how about naming window layouts in winner mode so you don't have to cycle through many levels of undo/redo to get back to what you want?

Comment: @OpenLearner Hm, if you want to name layouts, what would be the benefit of using winner mode over plain registers?

Answer (score 31):

I know you allready accepted an answer, however because I understand your question in another way (concerning layout) and this question showed up for me when I was in search for something to persist my emacs window layout, I would like to mention:

[workgroups.el](http://github.com/tlh/workgroups.el)

which purpose is to save and restore the way, emacs windows are layed out and many more.

Comment: This was what I was looking for when google drove me to this answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: workgroups.el is awesome, but it doesn't play nice (at all) with ECB :(... So I'm still using Escreen.

Answer (score 3):

Give [Layout Restore](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LayoutRestore) a try if you just want to restore the window layout later.

Comment: Layout Restore works  nicely, associating a layout to a buffer and providing a save layout, restore layout and delete layout *However* its code is old and uses advices that prevent other modes from operating.  The idea of associating a list of layouts to a buffer is a nice idea but I think the code should be looked at.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to persist a layout in your hard-drive, `desktop-save` is the option.

If you need to store multiple layouts during emacs' process lifetime (e.g. you connect to a long-running emacs daemon using `emacsclient`), you can use `C-x r f <register>` to store the frame layout in some register and `C-x r j <register>` for restore.

Since I now and then remotely connect to the work station to do sth, disconnect for a while and later reconnect, restoring layout helps me continue stuff seamlessly (note in this case window layouts stored by `C-x r w` would be gone).